# Mobile network performance on the background

Tags: android, performance, networking, mobile, measurement

All I want to do is monitor on the background network performance when I use an application, like watching a Youtube Video (e.g. downlink throughput, latency a.s.o).
I am aware of Android Apps like mobiPerf, which are great, but only provide results for specific tests. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It's still ongoing R&D but does exactly the thing you want. Check settings to enable the live monitor.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.netradar.netradar360

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can try Ixia's IxChariot.

IxChariot is a versatile product that is used for [testing network peformance](https://www.ixiacom.com/products-services/performance-monitoring) in various scenarios.

In your case, you can install the IxChariot endpoint on an Android device (download it from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ixia.ixchariot)) and use the endpoint to generate traffic to and from the device and measure its network performance, in a lab environment.

Additionally, you have to install a second endpoint on the IxChariot server hosted in a cloud or public network.

Both endpoints must be configured to connect to the Registration Server located on the same machine as the IxChariot server. Once this configuration is complete, you can use the web interface to run various tests on the mobile data connection.

The range of available tests includes TCP, UDP, RTP, and VoIP traffic, with unlimited or configurable data rates. The reported statistics include Throughput, One-Way Delay, Jitter, Loss Rate, and MOS Score. IxChariot is capable of sending bidirectional test traffic, thus testing both the inbound and outbound directions of the mobile data connection.

Full disclosure - I work as Sr. Marketing Engineer at Ixia.